# Server returning 503 in program but works when accessed through browser?

Tags: c#, http, webclient

I'm trying to make a site-specific video downloader for KissAnime.com in C# that takes a URL and gets all the video page URLs from that and then finds the mp4 link for the video and returns all the video URLs to the user for a batch download in Internet Download Manager or something.

Here is my problem:
Let's take this [Attack on Titan (Dub)](http://kissanime.com/Anime/Shingeki-no-Kyojin-Dub) page as an example. You can visit it in your browser just fine. However, if you try and access it through something like `webClient.DownloadString("thaturlgoeshere");`, it throws a WebException saying `The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.`.

Is there another way to get the HTML of a page? I read something about copying headers from a browser to make the site think my program is a human. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KissAnime.com, like many other sites, uses the Cloudflare Protection Layer which sends the browser a maths question to solve and send back. It does this to check if the browser is a real browser or just a bot, like your program.

Your best bet would be to use a headless browser like PhantomJS.

Answer (score 0):

The actual issue is that 503 is the verifying your browser section. You need to verify your browser, since it wouldn't work you need to use raw sockets to connect and send headers.